# print field number and field

Tags: sed, awk

I want to print the field number and field like this... Is awk the best way?  If so how?
The # of fields in the input line may vary.

```
input_line ="a|b|c|d" 
expected result:
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

I'm able to print the fields, but need help printing the field numbers.  Here's what I have

```
echo "a|b|c|d" |awk -F"|" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}'
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk command like:

```
echo "a|b|c|d" | awk -F"|" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i, $i}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` with a while loop should do the trick:

```
awk -F '|' '{ i = 1; while (i <= NF) { print i " " $i; i++; } }' <<< "a|b|c|d"
```